# Session se autodestruye

Tags: php7, session

Estoy teniendo problemas con las sesiones, después de validar el logeo inicio una session con 3 variables,
una de ellas la utilizo para informar, en la pantalla que abre, quien está logeado, hasta aquí no hay problema con la session,
en el encabezado coloco las variables de rutina para abrir session y verificar con isset si lo está.
El problema se me presenta con cualquier pantalla que quiera abrir a partir de ésta, ya que no pasa el isset de session del
encabezado, ya revisé las sugerencias en internet y las hice casi todas (no sé si habrán otras más), verifiqué el bloqueo de
las cookies, que no hubiera mas de un espacio en la sintáxis de inicio de la session, etc.
Lo que me llama la atención es que si tuviera algún problema de seteo de alguna variable de session en el Wampserver64, que es
el servidor que utilizo, no debería abrirme, por lógica simple, ni siquiera la primera pantalla después del logeo, pero no
es así.
Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, adjunto los códigos.

Seteo de las variables de session después del login

```
public function verifyUserLoginModel($loginData) {

   $user = $loginData["userName"];
   $pass = $loginData["userPass"];

   $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";

   $query_login = $this->conex->prepare($sql_select);
   $query_login->execute(array($user));
   $total_reg = $query_login->rowCount();

   if ($total_reg == 1) {

      if ($resultado = $query_login -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

         if (password_verify($pass, $resultado["password"])) {
            
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
            $_SESSION["user"] = $resultado["username"];
            $_SESSION["name"] = $resultado["name"];
            $_SESSION["password"] = $resultado["password"];
            $_SESSION["ipUserComputer"] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

            $json[] = array(
               'login' => "Password"
            );

         } else {

            $json[] = array(
                'login' => "NoPassword"
            );

        }

     }

  } else {

     $json[] = array(
        'login' => "NoCredentials"
     );

  }

  $query_login = null;
  $this->conex = null;

  $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
  echo $jsonstring;

}
```

Llamada de la primera pantalla

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../main/transData.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: datos,
  async: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
     var userLogin = JSON.parse(response);
     var procesado = userLogin[0].login;

     switch (procesado) {
        case 'Password':
           $('#loginTemplate').removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut');

           **window.location.href = '../views/modules/listInventoryView.php';**
           break;
            
        case 'NoPassword':
           $('#error-login-message span').text('Las Credenciales no son Válidas');
           $('#error-login-message').removeClass('msgOff');
           $('#error-login-message').addClass('msgOn');

           setTimeout(() => {
              $('#error-login-message').css('display','block');
           }, 1000);
           break;

        case 'NoCredentials':
           $('#error-login-message span').text('Las Credenciales no son Válidas');
           $('#error-login-message').removeClass('msgOff');
           $('#error-login-message').addClass('msgOn');

           setTimeout(() => {
              $('#error-login-message').css('display','block');
           }, 1000);
           break;
     }

  }
});
```

Encabezado de la primera pantalla

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

  require_once "../../core/configGral.php";

  if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {

     $user = $_SESSION['user'];
     $name = $_SESSION['name'];
     $computer = $_SESSION['ipUserComputer'];

  } else {

     echo "<script>alert('¡Usuario NO REGISTRADO!')</script>";
     header("Refresh:0 , url = ../../main/logout.php");
     exit;

  }
?>
```

Llamada a la otra pantalla por medio de un botón

```
$('#btn-open-list-suppliers').on('click', function() {

   $('#body-list-inventory').removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut');
   **window.location.href = '<?php echo SERVERURL; ?>views/modules/listSuppliersView.php';**

});
```

Encabezado de la segunda pantalla

```
<?php session_start();?>

   <?php

      require_once "../../core/configGral.php";

         if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {

            $user = $_SESSION['user'];
            $name = $_SESSION['name'];
            $computer = $_SESSION['ipUserComputer'];

      } else {

         echo "<script>alert('¡Usuario NO REGISTRADO!')</script>";
         header("Refresh:0 , url = ../../main/logout.php");
         exit;

      }
?>
```

Archivo configGral.php

```
<?php

  const SERVERURL = "http://localhost/desarrollos/xxxxxx/inventario/";
  const COMPANY = "xxxxxx";
  date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');

  $fecha_corta_ing = date('Y-m-d');
  $fecha_corta_esp = date('d-m-Y');
  $hora = date('H:i:s');
  $fecha_hora_ing = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $fecha_hora_esp = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

  $intdate = strtotime($fecha_hora_ing);
  $year = date("Y", $intdate);
  $month = date("m", $intdate);
  $day = date("d", $intdate);
  $hour = date("H", $intdate);
  $minute = date("i", $intdate);
  $second = date("s", $intdate);
```

Se me ocurrió hacer una prueba destruyendo la session en la primera pantalla, justo despúes de pasar el isset, para luego
abrirla de nuevo y vi con asombro cómo me daba el error de que no podía destruir una session que no existe o que no está
iniciada.

Comment: Primero comprobaría con ```var_dump($_SESSION);``` si te imprime algo después de ```session_start();```.

Comment: Cómo describí al principio, la primera página pasa la validación de la session, utiliza la variable $name y la coloca en un label para darle la bienvenida al usuario, el problema es con las subsiguientes pantallas que quiera abrir.